# How to change text property of asp.net textbox with javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, textbox

I have a textbox that I want to change text property of it with javascript, but I can't do.

My sample code below, Can anyone say what is wrong? Thanks...

```
function openAdresYeni(p) {
        document.getElementById('hdnAdresIndex').innerText = p;         
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this :

```
function openAdresYeni(p) { 
    document.getElementById('hdnAdresIndex').value = p;
}
```

**NOTE :** By the way if your `hdnAdresIndex` is a server control, you should use control's ClientID property to get client side id :

```
function openAdresYeni(p) { 
    document.getElementById('<%= hdnAdresIndex.ClientID %>').value = p;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

use `value` instead of `innerText`

also, if you're not in asp.net mvc, the ID of the control is probably not what you expect. Look into the `myTextBox.ClientID` property on the asp.net control.